# I'm trying to find the grouped category's that have a average greater than x

Tags: sql

The problem is that when I run my query I receive the incorrect Average math back from what I get on a calculator when using the greater than statement.

What's happening is when the average is occurring it is only using values above the where clause value. What I want to happen is for it to GROUP the category's get the average of all the prices in that category and then only show me the ones above the value.

This version works because it is looking directly at the category without the greater than question.

```
SELECT CategoryID, AVG(Price)
FROM Products
WHERE CategoryID="3"
GROUP BY CategoryID
```

Returned Data

```
CategoryID  AVG(Price)
3           25.16
```

This is the version I'm having trouble with.

```
SELECT CategoryID, AVG(Price)
FROM Products
WHERE Price > 30
GROUP BY CategoryID;
```

Returned Data

```
CategoryID  AVG(Price)
1           154.75
2           41.95
3           51.3575
4           38.300000000000004
5           35.625
6           73.14750000000001
7           49.3
8           46.75
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `having`

```
SELECT CategoryID, AVG(Price)
FROM Products
GROUP BY CategoryID
having AVG(Price)>x
```

having is a group filter , so here you need having instead of where

Answer (score 0):

You want `having` - using `where` is just giving you the averages of prices that are over 30.

So:

```
SELECT CategoryID, AVG(Price)
FROM Products
GROUP BY CategoryID
having AVG(Price) > 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT CategoryID, AVG(Price)
FROM Products
--WHERE Price > 30
GROUP BY CategoryID;
HAVING AVG(Price) > 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HAVING` in this case. `HAVING` allows you to filter on *aggregated* (like an average) fields, while `WHERE` limits you to only the actual values in the data at rest. Try this:

```
SELECT CategoryID, AVG(Price)
FROM Products
GROUP BY CategoryID    
HAVING AVG(Price) > 30
```

[Here is a good tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/having-vs-where-clause/) on `HAVING` vs `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use the `HAVING` keyword to select from groups formed by `GROUP BY`. In this `HAVING`clause you can use all the different criteria to select from the groups.

```
SELECT CategoryID, AVG(Price)
FROM Products
GROUP BY CategoryID
HAVING AVG(Price) > x
```